# JQuery validation of radio group and text input option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jquery validate for the radio button group below with the following logic:
- if the first or second radio button is checked, the group is valid
- if the third radio button is checked, the text input must be filled for the group to be valid

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">Please state your marital status</label>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="q02div" name="q02div">
                <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> a) Not Married
                    <input type="radio" value="q2r1" id="q2r1" name="q02" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
                <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> b) Married
                    <input type="radio" value="q2r2" id="q2r2" name="q02" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
                <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"> c) Other (please specify)
                    <input type="radio" value="q2r3" id="q2r3" name="q02" />
                    <span></span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Other marital status" value="" name="q2r4" id="q2r4" maxlength="100" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added the following rules:

```
rules {
    q02: {
        required: function(element){
            return($("#q2r4").val()=="");
        }
    },
    q2r4: {
        required: "#q2r3:checked"
    }
}
```

However, the group is validated no matter of which button is checked and if the text input is filled or not. 
Could this be done with the rules or do i have to write some additional function? I've changed the rules a couple of times, with no luck. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
rules {
    q02: {
        required: true
    },
    q2r4: {
        required: "#q2r3:checked"
    }
}
```

The first rule makes the radio group required.  Must select 1, 2, OR 3.

The second rule only makes the text field required if 3 is checked.

There is no reason to look at the status of the text field and conditionally make the radio buttons required.  One of the three radio buttons is always required.

If you're concerned that 1 or 2 will be selected and the text box filled out anyway, you can use JavaScript to hide the text box when 1 or 2 is selected OR automatically select 3 when the user types in the box.

Comment: I've tried that also and a number of other combinations. I think that the radio group is validated because there is one button checked, no matter of what other rules are added. I'll keep trying to add some other rules, maybe i can solve this.

Comment: @crawler, I don't understand why this doesn't work for you.  Don't you want the radio group validated?  Meaning, shouldn't one radio option be selected in all cases?  That's what this is doing... plus if third is selected then text is required.  Why are you going backwards and trying to selectively restrict radio buttons based on text box?  There is a solution here someplace, it's just unclear what part of this you're trying to solve.